# mapping regular expression group matches

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the regular expressions `\(.*\)`, `\[.*\]`, `\{.*\}`, and `\<.*\>`. Is there a way to combine these regular expressions?

For example, I had in mind something like:
`([\(\[\{\<]).*\1`, but of course this matches `\(.*\(`, `\[.*\[`, `\{.*\{`, and `\<.*\<`.

My goal is to be able to match a previous regular expression group, but apply a function to the group before matching it.

Consider:

```
def match_pairs(pairs):
    re = '|'.join("({begin}.*{end})".format(begin=beg, end=end) for (beg, end) in pairs)
    return re
```

I'm considering using something similar to the above function for now, but ideally this function wouldn't return a really long regex. Do let me know if you think this question doesn't have any practical merit. I'm still curious to know if Python3 supports any feature like this, sort of how like `re.sub` can take a function as the replacement. If no such feature exists, how can I write `match_pairs` so that it can take in `["()", "[]", "[]", "{}"]` as an argument?

Comment: `(\(.*\)|\[.*\]|\{.*\}|\<.*\>)` ?

Comment: Well of course that would work, but I'm looking for something that can be more concise.

Comment: Three extra characters per pair ain't too bad. I don't think you're going to get much better. How many pairs are we talking?

Comment: @Blorgbeard In my actual application, I don't just have the kleen star match, I have something much more complicated that I'm trying to avoid repeating.

Comment: Since you asked: I don't think this question has any practical merit. Your function (Blogbeard's answer) does a good job as is. For more complicated applications, wrap the searching in more functions; don't hope for a much shorter regex.

Comment: Well, if it's not practical, I am curious if any such features exist.

Comment: I would use PyParsing

Comment: @JDong. Regexp has no built-in knowledge of these opening/closing character pairs, so they have to be specified explicitly in the pattern itself. There are no shortcuts. However, if you are using a factory function to generate the patterns, it's hard to see why you would care about their length.

Comment: @ekhumoro fair, so should I close this question? I'd still like to know the best way to write that factory function such that I don't have to input backslashes to the function.

Comment: @JDong. You could use `re.escape()` on the arguments to `format`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. I will close the question in 24 hours.

Comment: What's your goal here? Are you looking for a shorter way to write `(\(.*\)|\[.*\]|\{.*\}|\<.*\>)`? Or are you looking for a way to write that regex without copying the `.*` part 4 times?

Comment: @Rawing I assumed both goals were aligned, but the latter is my primary goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious (and shortest) regex for this task is `\(.*\)|\[.*\]|\{.*\}|\<.*\>`.

The downside is that you have four copies of the `.*` subpattern, so if you ever need to change it, you'll have to change it in 4 places. Luckily we can work around this problem with some use of capture groups:

```
(?:\(()|\[()|\{()|<()).*(?:\1\)|\2\]|\3\}|\4>)
```

[Online demo.](https://regex101.com/r/SSCrnQ/1)

This may look confusing, but it's actually very simple. The pattern is built like this:

```
(?:opening_char_1()|opening_char_2()|...).*(?:\1closing_char_1|\2closing_char_2|...)
```

This uses a fairly straightforward little trick: Each opening character (`(`, `[`, `{`, `<`) is accompanied by a capture group like so: `\[()`. This allows us to "remember" which opening character was matched - if capture group 1 matched, we know the opening character was `(`. If capture group 2 matched, the opening character was `[`, and so on. So we simply use backreferences (`\1`, `\2`, etc) to find out what the opening character was, and then match the corresponding closing character.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!